# How can I load jQuery before navigating to a new page with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS application that uses ui-router. It's a SPA application and I want to keep the initial load time down as much as possible. When a user clicks on a link to go to some map page on my application I need to load jQuery. Here's the ui-router config code:

```
var homeMap = {
    name: 'home.map',
    parent: 'home',
    url: '/:map',
    views: {
        'root': {
            templateUrl: '/Content/app/home/partials/home.html',
        },
        'content': {
            templateUrl: function (stateParams) {
                return '/Content/app/home/partials/' + stateParams.content + '.html';
            },
        }
    }
};
```

Is there a way that I can do the loading of jQuery and confirm that it has finished before moving the user to the new page. Note that I need to do this with some kind of resolve inside the ui-router code block rather than coding any script elements in my page that I load.

Comment: Have you considered RequireJS?

Comment: Yes, RequireJS would be good for this situation I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the resolve block, setup a promise and return it, load jQuery, then poll until it exists on the window object. Once it does, resolve the promise:

```
resolve:{
    jquery:  function($http, $q){
        if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
            // load jQuery
            var wait = setInterval(function() {
                if (typeof jQuery === 'function') {
                    deferred.resolve();
                    clearInterval(wait);
                }
            }, 100);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ITUXoykOmmE8rMojXNXd?p=preview)

Comment: what would be a good way for me to load jQuery to replace your comment? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Sorry, I left my answer somewhat generic to keep the code sample from getting too long. I demonstrated a pure JS method in [**the demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ITUXoykOmmE8rMojXNXd?p=preview) I linked. Take a look in `script.js`.

Answer (score 1):

`$locationChangeStart` might help with what you want, there's also `$routeChangeStart` depending on which is more suitable for your situation.

So something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
    //Load JQuery here
});
```